# What is the api for Calling Home Screen on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to trigger an event when pressing the home button. Is there any particular api for using that?

Thanks

Shawn

Answer (score 3):

Use applicationWillResignActive and/or applicationWillTerminate. You have a limited amount of time to do stuff in these functions, so be quick.

Comment: See, this is what I am having problem with. I am using Unity3d and was hoping once I click home button, it terminates the application, but apparently it seams like the application is still running in background. So, I wanted to see what are my options of actually getting the application really terminated rather than by going to the background after "Home Button", is clicked.

Comment: Set the value UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to YES in your info.plist file in that case.

Comment: @Shawn Sngh Why didn't you say that in your question, then?

Comment: Ceejayoz, apologies on that side, I am not sure if I want to totally terminate the application, will play around a little to see if that's a good option or not.

Answer (score 0):

Make your viewController a NSApplication delegate and the implement

```
- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```